# web.py: avoid global instances?

Tags: python, instance, global, web.py

the last few weaks, I am playing a little bit with the Web.py framework. As my application is now getting bigger and bigger, I want to restructure the sourcecode and put code fragments in different classes. Now, I don't really know where I should create my object instances if I need them in different web.py classes. Let us assume, my sourcecode looks like:

```
import web
import myclass

urls = (
    '/', 'index',
    '/test', 'test'
)

#should i make my instance global...
my = myclass.myClass()

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        #...or should i make my instance local: my = myclass.myClass() 
        pass

    def GET(self):
        item = my.getItem()
        return item

    def POST(self):
        pass

class index:
   def __init__(self):
       #...or should i make my instance local: my = myclass.myClass() 
       pass

    def GET(self):
        date = my.getDate()
        return date

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Now, I want to access the methods `getItem()` and `getDate()` (which belong to the instance `my`), if the appropriate sites in my webbrowser are called. My question is now: Should I make the instance global or is it better, if I make it local? I really don't like global instances, but I don't see any other way as to make it global. Sure, it would be possible, to create a local instance, but then, every time the page loads, a new instance would be created, right? Normally, this wouldn't be a problem, but `myclass` accesses a serial port, so I need to make sure, that only one instance is created.

Am I missing something or is a global instance the only possible solution to accomplish this?

Comment: It would be better to make it a global object, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I came to the conclusion, that global instances are the way to go here. However, one must be careful with global instances if they are used together with the web.py auto reload mode. In auto reload mode, a global instance is created every time a new page loads. If you want to avoid that, you have to use something like this:

```
import web
import serial

urls = ("/(.*)", "test"
       ) 

web.config.debug = True

if(web.config.debug): 
    #in debug mode, make sure that global serial instance is only created at start up
    if not hasattr(serObj, "_email"):
        serObj = serial.Serial(0, 9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE) 
        web._serObj = serObj
    else:
        serObj = web._serObj  

class test:
    def GET(self):
        return "Test"

    def POST(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain why the test on the existence of the `_email` attribute on `serObj` (which appears to be a serial interface handle?) allows to determine if the global `Serial` object has already been created?  Also I suppose it might be useful if the example shows `serObj` being used in the `GET` method.